# How to: Convert user input as an interger to a String

Tags: java, class

//This is my first class. Used to set up constructor and mutator methods.

```
public int setColor(int setColor) //Mutator
{
  colorCode = setColor;
  return setColor;
}

public String setColorOfAuto(String toString)
{
  if (colorCode == 1);
  {
    toString = ("Red");
    return toString;
  }
}
```

My question is. How can I get user input, as an integer, (either 1,2,3,4) to convert to String (1 for Red, 2 for Blue, 3 for White, 4 for Black).
These objects have already been declared and initialized but I chose not to add that section due to over bearing weight of programming. Also, this made it look cleaner and hopefully easier to navigate through. Constrained to the use of mutator and accessor methods only.

Thanks.

Comment: If this is not enough information, I will add the rest of my Program to hopefully make this more clear.

Comment: you want to assign the string color to an attribute of that class?

Comment: Yes. On my other program that uses these classes it has a scanner for colorCode. If they input 1, i want to convert that input to the string setColorOfAuto (1 = "red") does that make sense?

Comment: what's wrong with the switch since they are only 4?

Comment: What do you mean? My actual program contains all if statements for 2, 3, 4 and  anything out of bounds. I just wanted to simplify it for assistance sake.

Answer (score 0):

you can use enums instead to map between integers and strings such as below

```
public enum Color {
        RED(1), BLACK(2), WHITE(3);
        private int value;

        private Color(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Color col : Color.values()) {
            System.out.println("Color Value: " + col.value + " - Color Name: " + col);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, If i cannot get someone to assist me in the use of Mutator and Accessor methods then, I'll try to implement this into my coding. Thanks for you time! But as I said, I'm constricted to more basic means of programming at the moment.

Comment: This is the idea, you could define the mapping in the enum as for the constructor you read an integer, and then check the enum to get the string out of it as in the example, this is one way to do it

Answer (score 0):

This is what enumerations are for. An enumeration is a complete, ordered listing of all the items in a collection.

So in your example, you can define `Color` as an enumerated type:

```
enum Color {
  RED(1),
  BLUE(2),
  WHITE(3),
  BLACK(4);
}
```

If you were to print out an instance of `Color` that's been instantiated as red, it would look like this: `RED`.

You can even have a custom description for each of these as well, if you'd like them to say something else:

```
enum Color {
  RED(1),
  BLUE(2),
  WHITE(3),
  BLACK(4);

  private final String description;

  Color(int value) {
    switch(value) {
      case 1: 
        description = "The color of blood.";
        break;
      case 2:
        description = "As blue as the ocean.";
        break;
      //etc...
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

If you insist on having a `Color` class (which you shouldn't -- there's no reason to include all of the overhead of a class for such a simple purpose):

```
class Color {

  int value;
  String description;

  Color(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    setColor(value);
  }

  private setColor(int value) {
    switch (value) {
    case 1: 
      this.description = "Red";
      break;
    case 2:
      this.description = "Blue";
      break;
    //Etc...
    }
  }

  public setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
    description = setColor(value);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

Edit:

For your *exact* use-case:

You want to pull a number from some `Scanner` object, use it to instantiate a Color class or enumeration, and then take the value.

For the purposes of this example, I'm going to assume you have the `Color` class that I have above. You will have to complete the switch statement inside of that class for this to work.

```
//Within main
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
// Print user prompts
// ...
int colorSelection = stdin.nextInt();

Color c = new Color(colorSelection);

// Print the color
System.out.println(c);
```

If you want to print the color in `ALL-CAPS`, you can use the same code above but with the very first enumeration that I have listed in my answer instead of the `Color` class. If you want custom descriptors, use the second enumeration and complete the `switch` statement.

Comment: I see your point and i enjoy this concept. But, the thing is. I have to have a scanner that is used for the input of either 1,2,3,4. (colorCode). Then, it returns those values to strings. Such as                                                          Input which color your car is. *user input* : 1                                                  Okay, you chose the color Red.

Comment: Right. You can still use a scanner. Get the user input from the Scanner, and then pass it into the Color enumeration or use it to initialize the Color class. You can get the string value you want by printing out the enumeration, or by printing out the class object.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm pretty new to java. Could you show me a small example of what you mean by pass it into the color enumeration?